# Scrollbars missing from simple page: jquery and jscrollpane

Tags: jquery, scrollbar, jscrollpane

I have created a VERY simple page, hoping to show scrollbars, but I can't.  I must be missing something obvious..

Can someone have a look at suggest what is missing?

http://www.haast.ca/Pages/Products/HAAST/License.htm

Thanks!

Comment: In the EULA? I see a scrollbar.

Comment: I have firefox 3.6.3, and I see the UELA in text in a DIV (1 px border), but no scrollbar on the right.  Same in 8.0.6xx.  Are you sure you are looking for a scrollbar INSIDE the DIV box (not the browser scrollbar on the right of the window)?  I'm trying to diagnose a jscrollpane issue...so ignore the browsers own scrollbars.

Comment: Ah. Yes, the scrollbar was inside the DIV, but it was because I had JS turned off and Chrome was smart enough to know I needed one for that DIV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure you are including the CSS file required by jScrollPane:

http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/style/jquery.jscrollpane.css

As described in "How to use" on the jScrollPane homepage:

http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/

Comment: That was it - not sure how I missed it! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Chrome 10.x here, no scrollbar.
I just tested, if you remove the `width` from the outer div and set `overflow:auto;`, the scrollbar appears.

Comment: hmmm...I have only one DIV, and the associated class set width to 100% and overflow:auto.  So I removed the width:100% (in the CSS file), but still the same result...